# Spring Boot + OUD to pull userRole based on the userId

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

Hi All am working on Spring boot application , now i have a requirement to connect to OUD to get the userRole based on the userId .

I had done the same before using the LDAP and i could not find what is OUD and how this is different from LDAP . how to implement OUD implementation using the Spring Boot .

Googled for quite sometime , could not find out the required details , if someone had done this before or any pointers to would be realy helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OUD stands for - [Oracle Unified Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oud/index.html), and its an Oracle alternative of LDAP. And they provide REST services to access the required details, [REST API for OUD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/unified-directory/12.2.1.3/oudrt/index.html). You can check what type of API you required here and use it.

I would also recommend going through their documentation, [Fusion Middleware Administering Oracle Unified Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oud/OUDAG/toc.htm) to understand the concepts.

As per my understanding OUD will be deployed somewhere so you can access it from Spring boot by calling the required services specified in the API reference with required parameters.

Comment: i read all throught those docs  but not sure whether oud has the rest end point . any java sample exist for this

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/unified-directory/12.2.1.3/oudrt/rest-endpoints.html. The Endpoints. And this step explains how to call it,https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/unified-directory/12.2.1.3/oudrt/QuickStart.html